# What do I do when the last XFCE4 panel dissapears?

Tags: xfce

I use XFCE because it's so lightweight, but it's the most shitty GUI environment I've ever seen, including Windows 95. I just installed a plain Debian with xfce and I created one bottom panel with clock, window buttons and applications menu. Afterwards I logged off (through applications menu button) and I logged as `root` to add main user to `sudo` group.

After logging back to main user, panel was gone. Since that was the last panel, I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Panels are managed by right-clicking a panel, so my question is: how do I manage (restore) panels once they're gone. However since then I noticed it's just some bug - on further logins the panel appears after error prompt announcing that no panel is running...

Comment: @clearkimura Yeah, if it wasn't for that context menu, I'd be lost. Shortcut keys also work, even newly defined ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore a new Xfce panel from the Xfce Settings Manager. It can be accessed either from the context menu (right-click on mouse) or the run dialog.

- From context menu: On Xfce Desktop, do right-click to open the context menu and go to **Applications > Settings > Settings Manager**
- From run dialog: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to show run dialog, then type `xfce4-settings-manager` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

In the **Xfce Settings Manager**, look for menu called **Panel** and click on it. If you don't have any Xfce panel running, a dialog box appear like screenshot and asking "Do you want to start the panel? ..." like so.

[image: xfce4-panel-question-dialog]

In the dialog box, click **Execute**. The result: an empty, new panel will appear somewhere on the Desktop (may be an unextended panel at 10% size). On the empty panel, user can do a right-click and click **Panel Preferences...** already.

**Important**: Save the changes before log out.

Ensure to select the option `Save session for future logins`, then only log out. Log in again and user will see the panel remains intact.

Finally, the next time you log out, you should deselect/remove the option to avoid making unnecessary changes.